# Merging multiple polygon shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, merge

I want to merge two polygon shapefiles into one without losing the attributes using ArcMap 10.1. To be exact I am creating a geological map and have some geologic formations in one shapefile and some other formations in another shapefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **[Merge (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000)** geoprocessing tool.

It should give you a merged polygon with all the attributes intact.